# New measures to reduce bad answer flood on high traffic questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-quality

I think it is a fairly well recognized phenomenon that questions in some tags attract more terrible answers at faster speed than others. And the site already does a fairly decent job at taking care of them. I am not sure how many of them get flagged, but they usually end up deleted after a few downvotes.

I don't have any statistics here, so maybe someone how has access to the mod tools would be a bit more informed here than I am.

It seems to me that given a lot of these terrible posts are coming from new users or low rep users well on their way to a question ban, that we should be able to deal with the problem with even less user intervention.

I also think the current situation of being bombarded at the beginning with tons of answers which later disappear might be confusing to the questioner. I think we can do better.

**I propose a (short) automatic protect interval of 5-10 minutes on new questions to the site.** This should be accompanied by a helpful message different from the normal protected question message indicating that after they have thought about it and still want to post, that they will be able to do so shortly; inviting them to proofread and improve their post in the meantime.

I expect to probably get downvoted for this because the consensus seems to be that this is a solved problem. While I feel that the current system *works*, I feel it could work *better*. This proposal might also be counterproductive.

I am probably missing something important, so feel free to criticize brutally.

Comment: @gnat I feel my proposal is less intrusive than that, but I do find the answers relevant.

Comment: The current rule also doesn't seem to react to self-deleted answers, which is part of what I am describing.

Comment: Proposals like this generally require some research on [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/), with numbers and maybe a graph, to demonstrate that the problem is *real* and that the proposed solution would be *effective*.

Comment: The problem with an automatic protection is that I don't think it would help cut down on answers. Protecting a question prevents answers from <10 rep users, but it's much higher rep users answering questions like this. We already know that few people read banners and whatnot that we put in front of them before answering, so even that might not have much of an effect.

Comment: Ok this post was mostly based on anecdotal evidence. IF I have time, I might try my hand at the data explorer or something.